# Contact method for a frame

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement a contact method to know when my player block has touched the yellow frame. Below is the code I have so far. When i drag the player block to the yellow frames nothing happens.

[image]

```
import SpriteKit
import iAd

struct BitMask {
    static let player:   UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let obstacle: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let frame:    UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let player = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)

    // setup scene's physics body (setup the walls)
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)

    // get current screen size
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    print("screenWidth:  \(screenSize.width) screenHeight: \(screenSize.height)")

    // setup play scene
    let playScreen = SKSpriteNode(color: .clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 370, height: 370))

    // y position adjustment
    let yFrame = 65
    playScreen.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY - CGFloat(yFrame))

    // create the rectangle which will represent physics body.
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -playScreen.size.width/2, y: -playScreen.size.height/2), size: playScreen.size)

    // apply physics conditions to the play scene
    playScreen.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: rect)
    playScreen.physicsBody?.friction = 0

    // add play scene to the frame
    addChild(playScreen)

    let playerScreenFrame = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: playScreen.size.width, height: playScreen.size.height))
    playerScreenFrame.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY  - CGFloat(yFrame))
    playerScreenFrame.fillColor = .clearColor()
    playerScreenFrame.strokeColor = UIColor(rgba: "#E9BD00")
    playerScreenFrame.lineWidth = 3;
    addChild(playerScreenFrame)

    let bottomRect = CGRectMake(frame.midX, frame.midY - CGFloat(yFrame), playScreen.size.width, playScreen.size.height)
    let bottom = SKNode()
    bottom.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: bottomRect)
    addChild(bottom)
    bottom.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BitMask.frame
    bottom.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BitMask.player
    bottom.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BitMask.player

    // set up player block
    player.name = "player"
    player.fillColor        = UIColor(rgba: "#E9BD00")
    player.strokeColor      = .blackColor()
    player.position = CGPoint(x:frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2  - CGFloat(yFrame))
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
    player.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    player.physicsBody!.friction = 0
    player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    addChild(player)
    player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask     = BitMask.player
    player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask  = BitMask.obstacle | BitMask.frame
    player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask    = BitMask.obstacle | BitMask.frame

    // set gravity to 0
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0)

    // set the scene as the delegate to be notified when two bodies collide
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

}
```

my contact method is as follows:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.obstacle) {
        // do your thing 
        print("Player contacted with obstacle")
        self.view?.paused = true
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == BitMask.frame) {
        // do your thing
        print("Player contacted with frame")
        self.view?.paused = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are trying to check for contact between two static bodies, but SpriteKit will not generate any contact events unless at least one body is dynamic.

In your case, the reason for this is related to the fact that edge-based physics bodies are static by default, and your player is static as well, means no contacts.

To fix this, you should set [dynamic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic) property on player's physics body to `true`, like this:

```
player.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!